# Is there a ListBox control that supports touch?

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll

I need a listBox control for WPF, but with touch scrolling.  Something that features smooth scrolling like in WP7?  The application will be used with a standard touchscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListBox and DataGrid already implement touchscreen.

With a mouse you can't see it because it's not possible to scroll on every part of the listbox, but on my 22 inch touch screen, with default properties it's possible